# Remove Facebook and Gmail contacts

Tags: contacts, sync, gmail, facebook

Some time ago I have synced my Facebook contacts (using Facebook for Android app) with my contacts. I also have my Gmail account synchronized. Having all those contacts is too much.

I went to `Account and synchronization` and turned off Facebook synchronization. Also in Google account I unchecked the `Synchronize contacts` box (however I still synchronize Gmail, Picasa, Calender and Google Reader).

Now the contacts are not in my contact list, but when I want to send SMS, I still have to browse trough all Gmail, Facebook and local contacts. That's too many entries and it's hard to find the right number. **How to get rid of Gmail and Facebook contacts completely?**

Also, when I go to `Dialer`, all my Facebook friends, who shared their phone numbers, appear there. **How to remove those entries also?**

I'm using Android 2.3.5

Comment: Do you use the stock SMS App?

Comment: Yes, my device has vanilla Android without any branding/mods/custom UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On `Contacts` tab of stock contacts app, hit `Options` button. Then, choose `more` ~> `Display Options`.

On this screen, un-check `Only contacts with phone numbers`. Then, check all accounts whose contacts you want to delete (like Facebook, all Gmail groups). And, un-check all accounts whose contacts you don't want to delete (like Phone, SIM). Tap `Save` button after you finished checking and un-checking.

On `Contacts` tab, hit `Options` button again. Choose `Delete` this time. On next screen, tap `Select all` and then `Delete` button. Done!

After this, again go to display options to display your contacts which weren't deleted.

Comment: The trick is, that I needed to check at least `Local contacts` as well. Otherwise list would be empty when I go to `Delete`.

Comment: @Tschareck No... Delete pulls list from current view.